# Unable to find resources after rebuilding and cleaning project

Tags: java, android

Trying to finish up initial build of project but it isn't compiling. It isn't recognizing R.layout.activity_list, R.id.fragment_container, and  R.id.article_fragment.

The build was based off of another project (setting up a database). I had copied the .XML over and it seems as though it won't register the three above to any kind of resource or even suggest what I should do.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.justin.timeactivitytracker;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


/**
 * Created by Justin on 2015-04-11.
 */
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements ActivityListFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        ActivityListFragment firstFragment = new ActivityListFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}
@Override
public void onArticleSelected(long position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the CountryListFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ActivityDetailFragment articleFrag = (ActivityDetailFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the CountryDetailFragment to update its content
        //articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ActivityDetailFragment newFragment = new ActivityDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ActivityDetailFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.justin.timeactivitytracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application

    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: what about `R.java`..?

Comment: @Abhishek it doesn't seem to be creating it, even after rebuilding and cleaning

Comment: did you try deleting any import to an R.java class, Remove, if any import android.R;

Comment: Even after deleting the imports, the errors still exist and it doesn't regenerate R.java

Comment: Restart your IDE, build again..if it's not getting generated even after that then check your .xml for errors ....sometimes problem can be with the drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, even after going through the .xml, I can't find any errors. Could it be that my Android Studio is messed up and not generating for any particular reason? 

I've uploaded the project to https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwbhvzcaf5r3bcf/TimeActivityTracker.zip?dl=0